# EF Eager loading include multiple

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have this Repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbEntitySet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        this.context = context;
        this.dbEntitySet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this.dbEntitySet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string include)
    {
        return this.dbEntitySet.Include(include);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
        foreach (var include in includes)
            query.Include(include);

        return query;
    }

    public void Create(T model)
    {
        this.dbEntitySet.Add(model);
    }

    public void Update(T model)
    {
        this.context.Entry<T>(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Remove(T model)
    {
        this.context.Entry<T>(model).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And I have a service which looks like this:

```
public class Service<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> repository;

    protected IRepository<T> Repository
    {
        get { return this.repository; }
    }

    internal Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.repository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<T>();
    }
}
```

My pages service looks like this (simplified):

```
public class PageService : Service<Page>
{

    // ...

    public IList<Page> GetPublished()
    {
        return this.Repository.GetAll(new string[] { "ForbiddenUsers", "ForbiddenGroups" }).Where(model => model.Published).ToList();
    }

    // ...

}
```

and just for clarity my **Page** looks like this:

```
public enum PageType
{
    Root,
    System,
    Page,
    Link,
    Group
}

public partial class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateModified { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string ViewData { get; set; }
    public string ViewTitle { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public PageType Type { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Lineage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public bool Restricted { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Page Parent { get; set; }
    public MenuPage MenuPage { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> ForbiddenUsers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> ForbiddenGroups { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this code, **ForbiddenUsers** and **ForbiddenGroups** are always null.
If I examine the call stack and I can see that the query that is generated looks like this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
[Extent1].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
[Extent1].[DateModified] AS [DateModified], 
[Extent1].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
[Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
[Extent1].[Path] AS [Path], 
[Extent1].[ViewData] AS [ViewData], 
[Extent1].[ViewTitle] AS [ViewTitle], 
[Extent1].[Link] AS [Link], 
[Extent1].[Published] AS [Published], 
[Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
[Extent1].[Order] AS [Order], 
[Extent1].[Lineage] AS [Lineage], 
[Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
[Extent1].[Restricted] AS [Restricted], 
[Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted]
FROM [dbo].[Pages] AS [Extent1]
```

As you can see, that is completely ignoring my includes.

If I change my service method to this:

```
public IList<Page> GetPublished()
{
    return this.Repository.GetAll("ForbiddenUsers").Where(model => model.Published).ToList();
}
```

and run my code, **ForbiddenUsers** is now populated and the call stack shows the correct generated query (too big to paste in here).

I need to allow multiple includes but I can not figure out why they are not working....

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should assign included query back to your query variable, because [QueryableExtensions.Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220202%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) creates new `DbQuery<T>` instead of modifying existing one. Also I suggest you to use `params` for included paths:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(params string[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
    foreach (var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);

    return query;
}
```

That will allow you pass all included paths without explicit array creation:

```
public IList<Page> GetPublished()
{
    return Repository.GetAll("ForbiddenUsers", "ForbiddenGroups")
                     .Where(model => model.Published)
                     .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you :) I love the params thing too, which is why I marked you as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
   foreach (var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);

    return query;
```

Comment: Actually we posted almost at same time, you even was a little faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Below, is an example in C#6.  In addition, note the use of the ***nameof*** operator to make the code more maintainable, so that the string values of the property names do not need to be manually updated on renaming.

```
// Assign the property names
var navigablePropertyNames = new[]
{
    nameof(ParentEntity.Id),
    nameof(ParentEntity.Name),
    nameof(ParentEntity.Description)
};

// Do the inclusion
GetAll(navigablePropertyNames);
```

So for your specific requirements:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(params string[] inclusions)
{
    var qry = this.dbEntitySet.AsQueryable();

    foreach(var inclusion in inclusions)
    {
        qry  = qry.Include(inclusion);
    }

    return qry;
}
```

Usages:

```
// either 
var resultSet1 = GetAll(nameof(ParentEntity.Id),
    nameof(ParentEntity.Name),
    nameof(ParentEntity.Description));

// or
var propertyNames = new[] {
    nameof(ParentEntity.Id),
    nameof(ParentEntity.Name),
    nameof(ParentEntity.Description)};

var resultSet2 = GetAll(propertyNames);
```